# How to understand this Grid.Clip transform?

Tags: .net, wpf, win-universal-app

I am learning SplitView control by reading its template. In the template, there is a transform called PaneClipRectangleTransform, to transform Grid.Clip of the pane area. Below XAML is part of state change from "Closed" to "OpenOverlayLeft".

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PaneClipRectangleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX">
  <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.35" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="0"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

How do I understand this part of code? What is the animation and what is the visible/invisible effect?

Answer (score 1):

Considering part of the XAML template of the SplitView control:

```
<Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
..
..
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneGridLength, FallbackValue=0, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
      <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition2" Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <!-- Content Area -->
   <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <Border Child="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
      <Rectangle x:Name="LightDismissLayer" Fill="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   </Grid>

   <!-- Pane Content Area-->
   <Grid x:Name="PaneRoot"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Visibility="Collapsed"
         Background="{TemplateBinding PaneBackground}"
         Width="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
        <Grid.Clip>
           <RectangleGeometry x:Name="PaneClipRectangle">
              <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                 <CompositeTransform x:Name="PaneClipRectangleTransform"/>
              </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
           </RectangleGeometry>
        </Grid.Clip>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="PaneTransform"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
..
..
</Grid>
```

Both of the "ContentRoot" grid and "PaneRoot" grids are placed in the same "Root" grid. As you see, Grid.Row property of the PaneRoot is set to default(0) and Grid.ColumnSpan is set to "2". It means both of the Content and Pane are placed in the same cell. This is the default settings with `Overlay` mode.

[image]

**Opened Pane**

So when the pane is open, there is no need to have pane clipping or transform for the pane. That's what you mentioned from the state transition from "Closed" to "OpenOverlayLeft":

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PaneClipRectangleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX">
    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.35" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="0"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

and also

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PaneClipRectangleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX">
   <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
   <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.35" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="0"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

As you see, for both Clipping and Transform, values will be set to "0" after 0.35 seconds so pane become completely open. The initial values are those that are set when the pane is supposed to be closed. They are discussed below.

**Closed Pane**

The pane needs to be hidden in Overlay mode by default. Here is the values for PaneTranform and PaneClipRectangleTransform in OpenOverlayRight to Closed transition:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PaneTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX">
   <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.12" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.OpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PaneClipRectangleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX">
   <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.12" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="{Binding TemplateSettings.NegativeOpenPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

In order to hide the pane (in RTL direction), it is moved to left by its length, it is also totally clipped so that it does not appear in UI. As the pane is getting open, transform and clipping value will get close and closer to 0:

[image]

The way clipping and transform works should explain why clipping value is set negative pane length and transform value is set to positive pane length in close mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It contains some duplicate information. Also, I hope you could explain more about the storyboard of PaneClipRectangleTransform. Why does the clip rectangle move from OpenPaneLength on X axis to 0 on X axis, in other words, why does the clip move from positive location of the screen to the left of screen?

Comment: @Sheen The clip is related to the element not the screen, it works in combination with the Transform. I know that I did not explain everything but I was hoping it gives you some insight. its not easy for me to explain better without providing animations.

Comment: Now I understand. The clip is relative to the element. Thanks a lot.